# Performance problems using Vector3.ClampMagnitude

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, clamp

I'm using rigidbody in my player and I need constant clamping in velocity, but I noticed in the profiler that Vector3.ClampMagnitude is causing performance problems. Do you know any faster alternatives to clamp Rigidbody velocity?

Code in Fixed Update

```
  if (ent.playerRope.grappleRope.isGrappling)
                        {
                            //direction
                            Vector2 targetDir = (ent.playerRope.grapplePoint - ent.rb.position).normalized;
                           
                            //force to direction
                            ent.rb.velocity += (targetDir * ent.playerRope.launchSpeed) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
                            ent.rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(ent.rb.velocity, ent.playerRope.maxRopeVelocity);
                        }
```

Comment: How often is this run? I would expect ClampMagnitude time to be measured in nanoseconds, so you should be able to do fairly many before running into problems.

Comment: I run the method in fixed update where I also apply the main velocity to the rigidbody

Comment: Can you show the profiler?

Comment: I dare say that a `Sqrt` is going to be involved there which can be like waiting for paint to dry.   Make sure you are not calling that every frame in `Update()`.  _[Tell me more](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html)_

Comment: I'm adding the screen of the code and the profiler

Answer (score 0):

avoid using magnitude, use sqrMagnitude instead. Try this:

```
if (targetVelocity.sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Pow(maxSpeed, 2))
{
    targetVelocity = targetVelocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
}
```